# change li class depending on current webpage in MVC

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app with a `_Layout` page, that gathers the main nav bar.

For each li class there is a specific class to needed to highlight the current page.

```
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-parent-item current-menu-item page_item current_page_item">
  @Html.ActionLink("Home", "index", "Home")<i class="fa fa-home hidden-xs"></i>
 </li>
```

How can I add this to other li classes when on that current page, while removing it from the `Home` when browsing away from it.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could accomplish this is to extract the URL from `window.location.href`, extract the relevant part of the URL via regex, then figure out some way to match this up with the appropriate nav button, and give this button a class that would highlight it - like:

```
.current-page {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

A simpler solution would just be to add this class (or whatever) to the nav links on each individual view - something like this:

```
// <li id="about-me-section" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-parent-item current-menu-item page_item current_page_item">

$("#about-me-section").toggleClass("current-page");
$("#home-section").toggleClass("current-page");
```